# Different text for More TabbedPage (language resources source)

Tags: xamarin, tabs, resources, tabbedpage

As you can see on link bellow, after xamarin forms update to 4.3, you are able to put more tabs into TabbedPage. If you have more than 5 tabs, xamarin will cut last 5th one and create own tab "More" where will be list for rest of your tabs.

But my application using different language resources and even after switching of lang.(when all app is switched into diff lang.) the text of More tab is still "More". I would like to change text of that time for diff.lang.resources from my app.

Can you help me with this issue?
[Link for TabbedPage MoreTab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page)

Comment: You can change it via customizing your TabbedRenderer in each platform.

Comment: yes, but how? I dont know how to "catch" the "more" tab page which is created automaticly. Then I can change the name from resources.

Comment: I test custom renderer in `TabbedRenderer` and convenient for all tabs, but I cannot found this more tabs, using this way: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/376630#Comment_376630